# Loading passenger_module in Apache

Tags: apache, ruby-on-rails-3, passenger

I'm having problem loading `passenger_module` into Apache.

```
# /usr/local/apache/conf.d/passenger.conf

LoadModule passenger_module  modules/mod_passenger.so

<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
   PassengerRoot /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/locations.ini
   PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby
   PassengerInstanceRegistryDir /var/run/passenger-instreg
</IfModule>
```

Since I can't find `modules/mod_passenger.so` relative to the above config file, I specified the `mod_passenger` file that I found somewhere else which is at `/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_passenger.so`. So the new config would be:

```
LoadModule passenger_module  /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_passenger.so

<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
   PassengerRoot /usr/lib/ruby/1.8/phusion_passenger/locations.ini
   PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby
   PassengerInstanceRegistryDir /var/run/passenger-instreg
</IfModule>
```

Running `service httpd restart` yield me this error:

```
httpd: Syntax error on line 28 of /usr/local/apache/conf/httpd.conf: Syntax error on line 1 of /usr/local/apache/conf/includes/pre_main_global.conf: 
Syntax error on line 3 of /usr/local/apache/conf.d/passenger.conf: Cannot load /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_passenger.so into server: /usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_passenger.so: undefined symbol: ap_escape_html
```

It's actually loaded on the top of the apache config.

By the way, if I do:

```
/usr/bin/passenger-config validate-install
```

I'll get:

```
You are about to validate Passenger against the following
Apache installation:

  Apache 2.4.16
  apxs2     : /usr/bin/apxs
  Executable: /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd

However, 1 other Apache installation(s) have been found on your system:

  Apache 2.4.16
  apxs2     : /usr/local/apache/bin/apxs
  Executable: /usr/local/apache/bin/httpd
```

If I do chose `y`, I'll get:

```
 * Checking whether this Passenger install is in PATH... ✓
 * Checking whether there are no other Passenger installations... ✓
 * Checking whether Apache is installed... ✓
 * Checking whether the Passenger module is correctly configured in Apache... ✓
```

It'd be great if you guys can shared some light on this issue. Feel free to ask more info if you have to. Thanks in advance.

I'm using `centos-release-6-8.el6.centos.12.3.x86_64`

Answer (score 0):

I am running Centos 7, Apache 2.4 and Passenger 5.0.28 all installed with yum. I am running passenger as an apache module.

You have Centos 6 and it looks like your apache is a custom install, however I thought going through my config files might help.

The passenger config on my server is split between:

```
# /etc/httpd/conf.modules.d/10-passenger.conf

### Begin automatically installed Phusion Passenger load snippet ###

LoadModule passenger_module modules/mod_passenger.so

### End automatically installed Phusion Passenger load snippet ###
```

and

```
# /etc/httpd/conf.d/passenger.conf

### Begin automatically installed Phusion Passenger config snippet ###

<IfModule mod_passenger.c>
   PassengerRoot /usr/share/ruby/vendor_ruby/phusion_passenger/locations.ini
   PassengerRuby /usr/bin/ruby
   PassengerInstanceRegistryDir /var/run/passenger-instreg
</IfModule>

### End automatically installed Phusion Passenger config snippet ###
```

I can see the module itself, seems to reside in both `/etc/httpd/modules/mod_passenger.so` and `/usr/lib64/httpd/modules/mod_passenger.so`.
All apache modules show up in both directories and all the files look the same.

1. Did you install passenger running `passenger-install-apache2-module`?
2. Any other messages in the apache log (usually `/var/log/httpd/error_log`)?